# How to modify a value in one "cell" of a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, copy, dataframe

I have a very simple problem. I would like to change a value in a given column of a given row of a pandas data frame. I try to do it in the following way:

```
df['column3'].loc[this_date] = val
```

As a result I get the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

My interpretation of this warning is that by using columns name (`'column3'`) and `loc` I do not really access (refer to) the desired cell of the data frame. Instead, I create an object which is a copy of the "cell" object and then I try to change the value associated with this "copy-object".

What I do not understand is that it seems to work. In spite on the fact that pandas writes me that I try to modify the copy, I do modify the original data frame.

My question is how to make sure that I am really doing what I would like to do and how to do it in a "correct" way so that the pandas does not complain?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df.loc[this_date,'column3'] = val`? Your version is different from the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: The fact it works is incidental, it may not work which is why you get the warning, please try my previous comment, there should be no warning

Answer (score 1):

The reason of getting the warning is that `df` itself is a copy of some other dataframe object. I guess that you have some original dataframe `df_origin` and you get `df` from `df_origin` by some operation such as slicing. So `df` is a copy of `df_origin`. Then you try to set some value to `df` and the warning raises to tell you that this would not change the value in the original dataframe `df_origin`. 
One solution is to use a single variable to point to the dataframe object before and after slicing if you don't care for df_origin. Otherwise you can suppress the warning by `pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)`

Your way of setting value is fine, along with the following ones:

```
 df.ix[this_date, 'column3'] = val
 df.loc[this_date, 'column3'] = val
 df.at[this_date, 'column3'] = val
```

Comment: the warning is shown because chained indexing is not fine! it depends on the underlying data (whether it is s view) and if it's mixed dtype. If these are conditions hold then you will be setting a copy, hence the warning. The reason to not do chained indexing EVER is that there is no guarantee that your setting will work! there are a multitude of other indexing options available.