# Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame with iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657378/how-to-modify-a-value-in-one-cell-of-a-pandas-data-frame) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe). The difference is that I have to select row by position, as I do not know the index.

I want to do something like `df.iloc[0, 'COL_NAME'] = x`, but iloc does not allow this kind of access. If I do `df.iloc[0]['COL_NAME'] = x` the warning about chained indexing appears.

Comment: what version of python and pandas are you using? I'm not getting a 'chained indexing' warning on PY3.4.2 with pandas 0.16.1. Is there anything special about how you construct the dataframe?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

For mixed position and index, use `.ix`. BUT you need to make sure that your index is not of integer, otherwise it will cause confusions.

```
df.ix[0, 'COL_NAME'] = x
```

#### Update:

Alternatively, try

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('COL_NAME')] = x
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# ========================
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['col1', 'col2'], index=np.random.randint(1,100,10)).sort_index()

print(df)


      col1    col2
10  1.7641  0.4002
24  0.1440  1.4543
29  0.3131 -0.8541
32  0.9501 -0.1514
33  1.8676 -0.9773
36  0.7610  0.1217
56  1.4941 -0.2052
58  0.9787  2.2409
75 -0.1032  0.4106
76  0.4439  0.3337

# .iloc with get_loc
# ===================================
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('col2')] = 100

df

      col1      col2
10  1.7641  100.0000
24  0.1440    1.4543
29  0.3131   -0.8541
32  0.9501   -0.1514
33  1.8676   -0.9773
36  0.7610    0.1217
56  1.4941   -0.2052
58  0.9787    2.2409
75 -0.1032    0.4106
76  0.4439    0.3337
```

Comment: My index is the result of some selection, and it is composed of not correlative integers:eg,  [3,24, 34] ix[0] throws an error.

Comment: @luna1999 Then maybe try `reset_index` first so that you can use `df.loc[0, 'COL_NAME']`, which causes no confusion.

Comment: @luna1999 I've updated my code using `df.columns.get_loc`, and it should work for you. Let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: @luna1999 You are most welcome. Glad that it helped. :-)

Comment: @JianxunLi thanks for the ```.iloc``` tip. However, I am puzzled about a thing (correct me if I am wrong): if ```df.iloc[4:7] = x``` returns a copy ```df``` with values [4:7] set to ```x```, why ```df.iloc[4:7,df.columns.get_loc("C")] = x``` is setting to ```x``` to the original ```df```?

Comment: why does df.iloc[index]["column_name"]=value work?   the syntax works to retrieve a value

Answer (score 62):

One thing I would add here is that the `at` function on a dataframe is much faster particularly if you are doing a lot of assignments of individual (not slice) values.

```
df.at[index, 'col_name'] = x
```

In my experience I have gotten a 20x speedup. [Here](http://pyciencia.blogspot.com/2015/05/obtener-y-filtrar-datos-de-un-dataframe.html) is a write up that is Spanish but still gives an impression of what's going on.

Comment: old, but one thing about df.at is that you cant for example take the last index using: ```df.at[-1, 'col_name'] = x``` instead it'll add a new row with an index name of -1.

Answer (score 15):

If you know the position, why not just get the index from that?

Then use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[index, 'COL_NAME'] = x
```

Comment: `df.loc` is for label-based indexing, not for position-based indexing. You may be referring to doing something like `df.loc[df.index[0], 'COL_NAME'] = x`

Comment: An example would be nice. You may copy https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MartinThoma/e9b072c5314d3d5d2507aba8a86b0d6e/raw/7341c0adeedfcf77ef893a680cad154e4a5366ac/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 14):

another way is,  you assign a column value for a given row based on the index position of a row, the index position always starts with zero, and the last index position is the length of the dataframe:

```
df["COL_NAME"].iloc[0]=x
```

Comment: maybe add a brief discussion of how this is different than the other 4 answers and what the code is doing

Comment: For modern versions of pandas, you get a SettingWithCopyWarning when you try this (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: This works when we have specific index and we don't want to use reset_index. `df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('COL_NAME')] = x` doesn't change the values if we have specific index rather than usual integer indexes.

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
df.set_value('Row_index', 'Column_name', value)
```

`set_value` is ~100 times faster than `.ix` method. It also better then use  `df['Row_index']['Column_name'] = value`.

But since `set_value` is [deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15269) now so `.iat`/`.at` are good replacements.

For example if we have this data_frame

```
   A   B   C
0  1   8   4 
1  3   9   6
2  22 33  52
```

if we want to modify the value of the cell [0,"A"] we can do

```
df.iat[0,0] = 2
```

or `df.at[0,'A'] = 2`

Comment: I mentioned that set_value is deprecated be carefull and read the answer well before decide to downvote blindly

Comment: It has been seiad in this line => But since set_value is deprecated now so .iat/.at are good replacements.

Answer (score 5):

To modify the value in a cell at the intersection of row "r" (in column "A") and column "C"

1. retrieve the index of the row "r" in column "A"

   ```
       i = df[ df['A']=='r' ].index.values[0]
   ```
2. modify the value in the desired column "C"

   ```
       df.loc[i,"C"]="newValue"
   ```

Note: before, be sure to reset the index of rows ...to have a nice index list!

```
        df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to get the row index and then use df.loc or df.at.

```
# get row index 'label' from row number 'irow'
label = df.index.values[irow] 
df.at[label, 'COL_NAME'] = x
```

Comment: This is the best solution when you want to set multiple rows to the same value

Answer (score 1):

Extending Jianxun's answer, using [`set_value`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) mehtod in pandas. It sets value for a column at given index.

From pandas documentations:

> DataFrame.set_value(index, col, value)

To set value at particular index for a column, do:

```
df.set_value(index, 'COL_NAME', x)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: set_value is depreciated. Better to us "at"