# Writing List to Loaded Excel Workbook using dataframes or other

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I am having some trouble finding the best way to write a list to a loaded excel sheet and then saving the result as an xlsx. What I want my code to do is to take the lists that I have created and put them in specific columns of the loaded workbook. I think there is probably an easier way to do this using dataframes, but I do not know how. Ideally, I would like to save the formatting of the loaded workbook. My code does not work as it stands. I am using Spyder from Anaconda.

```
col_test = [1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L]
```

My code is this

```
import xlrt
from xlrd import open_workbook
rb = open_workbook("Excel FDT Master_01_update.xlsx")
s = rb.sheet_by_name('INPUT')
r = 5
for test in col_test:
    s.cell(row = r, column = 1).value = test
    r += 1
rb.save('didthiswork.xlsx')
```

Comment: It looks to me like you need Col 1 of row 5-9 assigned to each value in the list. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thanks.

Comment: "does not work" - what happens? Is `xlrt` a typo for `xlrd`? As far as I know xlrd is only for the .xls format, not .xlsx, for which you [should use openpyxl](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-excel/P6TjJgFVjMI/g8d0eWxTBQAJ).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

col_test = [1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L]
data = pd.read_excel('workbook.xlsx', 'INPUT')

# Write to specific column name
start_row = 5
for i, val in enumerate(col_test):
    data.iloc[start_row + i, 'COL_NAME'] = val


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
data.to_excel(writer, 'NewSheet')
```

Assigning values to particular [cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569384/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-with-iloc)

[read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

[to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array]

This is what I get when I try that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I am using 'B' as the COL_NAME

Comment: Um. I would do `data.head()` to show the first 5 rows and verify that 'B' is the proper column name

Comment: can you explain what data.head() will do? I do not understand what you mean, apologies.

Comment: Do `print(data.head())` and it will show you the first five rows with column names so you can get the actual column name to put into the code I provided in the answer