# Efficient Manipulation of Rows of Pandas DataFrames avoiding loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am wondering, if there is a possibility to do the following more efficient:

```
mins = argrelextrema(series, np.less)[0]
for i in mins:
    courses.loc[i, "MinMax"] = "Min"
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `courses.loc[mins, "MinMax"] = "Min"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569384/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-with-iloc

Comment: @pault thank you, unfortunately, this leads to a KeyError.

Comment: @Wen unfortunately I do not see that there is an array or a list used to adress certain rows. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: df.loc[np.array([1,3,4]),'MinMax']='Your value'

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] so we can try to recreate your issue?

Comment: Ok. the Problem was, that I have not created the column before - this is why  df.loc[np.array([1,3,4]),'MinMax']='Your value' gave me a KeyError. I have initialized the column with courses['MinMax'] = 0. Thank you for the help!