# Problem in updating a column value of a dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
GDP=pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv')
for i in GDP.index:
    if GDP.iloc[i]['Data Source']=="Korea, Rep.":
        GDP.iloc[i]['Data Source']="South Korea"
```

I tried to run the above code. But it does not update the string. And does not show any error.
The "ABW" data point is present in the dataframe. I also have given the link of the dataset.
https://github.com/pran9957/world-bank-data.git

Comment: try GDP.set_value(i,'Data Source',"South Korea")

Comment: Alternatively  this might  answer your question? [Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame with iloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569384/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-with-iloc)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
GDP['Data Source'].replace({
    'Korea, Rep.': 'South Korea'
}, inplace=True)
```